# 3D distance vectorization

Tags: python, vectorization

I need help vectorizing this code. Right now, with N=100, its takes a minute or so to run. I would like to speed that up. I have done something like this for a double loop, but never with a 3D loop, and I am having difficulties.

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
n = 12
r = np.sqrt(2)

x = np.arange(-N,N+1)
y = np.arange(-N,N+1)
z = np.arange(-N,N+1)

C = 0

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        for k in z:
            if (i+j+k)%2==0 and (i*i+j*j+k*k!=0):
                p = np.sqrt(i*i+j*j+k*k)
                p = p/r
                q = (1/p)**n
                C += q

print '\n'
print C
```

Comment: "I am having difficulties" isn't helpful - are you getting errors (provide traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Did you read the question? The code is correct, but slow, so OP wants to push some of the work to the fast numpy library instead of doing the loops in slow Python

Comment: Yeah, the code is correct, I just want it vectorized. I want to learn how to make it as efficient as possible

Comment: The answer involves scipy's `pdist`, and possibly bottleneck's `ss` (squared sum, which you want to potentiate again).

Comment: Is this 100 vectors, and all pairwise distances?

Comment: What should `C` equal?  I think you can easily do this with `x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(-N, N+1)]*3)`.

Comment: For N=3, C should be exactly 12
For N=100, C should be 12.1318....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meshgrid/where/indexing solution is already extremely fast. I made it about 65 % faster. This is not too much, but I explain it anyway, step by step:

It was easiest for me to approach this problem with all 3D vectors in the grid being columns in one large 2D `3 x M` array. `meshgrid` is the right tool for creating all the combinations (note that numpy version >= 1.7 is required for a 3D meshgrid), and `vstack` + `reshape` bring the data into the desired form. Example:

```
>>> np.vstack(np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(0, 2)]*3)).reshape(3,-1)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Each column is one 3D vector. Each of these eight vectors represents one corner of a `1x1x1` cube (a 3D grid with step size 1 and length 1 in all dimensions).

Let's call this array `vectors` (it contains all 3D vectors representing all points in the grid). Then, prepare a bool mask for selecting those vectors fulfilling your mod2 criterion:

```
    mod2bool = np.sum(vectors, axis=0) % 2 == 0
```

`np.sum(vectors, axis=0)` creates an `1 x M` array containing the element sum for each column vector. Hence, `mod2bool` is a `1 x M` array with a bool value for each column vector. Now use this bool mask:

```
    vectorsubset = vectors[:,mod2bool]
```

This selects all rows (:) and uses boolean indexing for filtering the columns, both are fast operations in numpy. Calculate the lengths of the remaining vectors, using the native numpy approach:

```
    lengths = np.sqrt(np.sum(vectorsubset**2, axis=0))
```

This is quite fast -- however, `scipy.stats.ss` and `bottleneck.ss` can perform the squared sum calculation even faster than this.

Transform the lengths using your instructions:

```
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        p = (r/lengths)**n
```

This involves finite number division by zero, resulting in `Inf`s in the output array. This is entirely fine. We use numpy's `errstate` context manager for making sure that these zero divisions do not throw an exception or a runtime warning.

Now sum up the finite elements (ignore the infs) and return the sum:

```
    return  np.sum(p[np.isfinite(p)])
```

I have implemented this method two times below. Once exactly like just explained, and once involving bottleneck's `ss` and `nansum` functions. I have also added your method for comparison, and a modified version of your method that skips the `np.where((x*x+y*y+z*z)!=0)` indexing, but rather creates `Inf`s, and finally sums up the `isfinite` way.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import bottleneck as bn

N = 100
n = 12
r = np.sqrt(2)


x,y,z = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(-N, N+1)]*3)
gridvectors = np.vstack((x,y,z)).reshape(3, -1)


def measure_time(func):
    import time
    def modified_func(*args, **kwargs):
        t0 = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = time.time() - t0
        print("%s duration: %.3f s" % (func.__name__, duration))
        return result
    return modified_func


@measure_time
def method_columnvecs(vectors):
    mod2bool = np.sum(vectors, axis=0) % 2 == 0
    vectorsubset = vectors[:,mod2bool]
    lengths = np.sqrt(np.sum(vectorsubset**2, axis=0))
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        p = (r/lengths)**n
    return  np.sum(p[np.isfinite(p)])


@measure_time
def method_columnvecs_opt(vectors):
    # On my system, bn.nansum is even slightly faster than np.sum.
    mod2bool = bn.nansum(vectors, axis=0) % 2 == 0
    # Use ss from bottleneck or scipy.stats (axis=0 is default).
    lengths = np.sqrt(bn.ss(vectors[:,mod2bool]))
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        p = (r/lengths)**n
    return  bn.nansum(p[np.isfinite(p)])


@measure_time
def method_original(x,y,z):
    ind = np.where((x+y+z)%2==0)
    x = x[ind]
    y = y[ind]
    z = z[ind]
    ind = np.where((x*x+y*y+z*z)!=0)
    x = x[ind]
    y = y[ind]
    z = z[ind]
    p=np.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/r
    return np.sum((1/p)**n)


@measure_time
def method_original_finitesum(x,y,z):
    ind = np.where((x+y+z)%2==0)
    x = x[ind]
    y = y[ind]
    z = z[ind]
    lengths = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        p = (r/lengths)**n
    return  np.sum(p[np.isfinite(p)])


print method_columnvecs(gridvectors)
print method_columnvecs_opt(gridvectors)
print method_original(x,y,z)
print method_original_finitesum(x,y,z)
```

This is the output:

```
$ python test.py
method_columnvecs duration: 1.295 s
12.1318801965
method_columnvecs_opt duration: 1.162 s
12.1318801965
method_original duration: 1.936 s
12.1318801965
method_original_finitesum duration: 1.714 s
12.1318801965
```

All methods produce the same result. Your method becomes a bit faster when doing the `isfinite` style sum. My methods are faster, but I would say that this is an exercise of academic nature rather than an important improvement :-)

I have one question left: you were saying that for N=3, the calculation should produce a 12. Even yours doesn't do this. All methods above produce 12.1317530867 for N=3. Is this expected?

Comment: I think I meant N=1 should give 12, which I was only using for a test case to see if I had things correct. Thank you so much for you input and help. I have learned a lot that I didn't even give thought to before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Bill, I was able to get this to work. Very fast now. Perhaps could be done better, especially with the two masks to get rid of the two conditions that I originally had for loops for.

```
    from __future__ import division
    import numpy as np

    N = 100
    n = 12
    r = np.sqrt(2)

    x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(-N, N+1)]*3)

    ind = np.where((x+y+z)%2==0)
    x = x[ind]
    y = y[ind]
    z = z[ind]
    ind = np.where((x*x+y*y+z*z)!=0)
    x = x[ind]
    y = y[ind]
    z = z[ind]

    p=np.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/r

    ans = (1/p)**n
    ans = np.sum(ans)
    print 'ans'
    print ans
```

Comment: I'm interested in where these conditions `(x+y+z)%2==0` and `(x*x+y*y+z*z)!=0` come from. Any physical meaning? The latter is just a filter for working around zeros? numpy can handle this.

Comment: Just FYI, `distances = distance.pdist(vectors, 'sqeuclidean')` might significantly speed up your `np.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)`, so maybe you wanna do this before filtering.

Comment: If I put it before the filtering, then how am I suppose to filter it? Also, those conditions come from a physical meaning of an atomic lattice that I am looking at. It's solid state physics, and these are the conditions I am using for the lattice sites, where the lattice is setup so that there will only be an atom if the coordinates are even when summed and nothing at the origin since it is the reference atom.

Comment: I would love for any advice on still how to make this better, but I would prefer you to just submit an answer, which I will happily select as the best.

Comment: Okay, now I got your code, I think. I am looking into this :-)